# Python Script is crashing and I don't know why

Tags: python, fibonacci

So I have 2 python programs that determine Fibonacci numbers. One uses memoinization and the other does not. Both work, and are able to determine the numbers when given an input.

However, I need to time them, which is where the 3rd program comes into play. I have it timing both functions for the 1st fib number to the 30th. When I run the 3rd program though, it just seems to crap out when it is calculating the 9th number, and I don't know why.

Can someone help me here? I have the code for all 3 programs below (and the error)

Thanks

---

Program 1

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

numIn = int(sys.argv[1])
result = fib(numIn)

print 'The %dth fibonacci number is %d' % (numIn, result)
```

---

Program 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

cache = [None]*100

def fib(n):

    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]

    else:
        if n < 2:
            cache[n] = n
        else:
            cache[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

        return cache[n]

numIn = int(sys.argv[1])
result = fib(numIn)

print 'The %dth fibonacci number is %d' % (numIn, result)
```

---

Program 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys,timeit,time

for i in range(1, 30):
        t1 = timeit.Timer('fib(%s)' % i, 'from problem1 import fib').timeit()
        t2 = timeit.Timer('fib(%s)' % i, 'from problem2 import fib').timeit()
        print 'The time for the %d th number is %f (Problem 1 - No Memo' % (i,t1)
        print 'The time for the %d th number is %f (Problem 1 - Memo' % (i,t2)
```

---

ERROR:

```
The 5th fibonacci number is 5
The 5th fibonacci number is 5
The time for the 1 th number is 0.215671 (Problem 1 - No Memo
The time for the 1 th number is 0.247929 (Problem 1 - Memo
The time for the 2 th number is 0.606024 (Problem 1 - No Memo
The time for the 2 th number is 0.269888 (Problem 1 - Memo
The time for the 3 th number is 1.027372 (Problem 1 - No Memo
The time for the 3 th number is 0.298666 (Problem 1 - Memo
The time for the 4 th number is 1.839900 (Problem 1 - No Memo
The time for the 4 th number is 4.466314 (Problem 1 - Memo
The time for the 5 th number is 3.117439 (Problem 1 - No Memo
The time for the 5 th number is 0.308327 (Problem 1 - Memo
The time for the 6 th number is 5.178429 (Problem 1 - No Memo
The time for the 6 th number is 8.496127 (Problem 1 - Memo
The time for the 7 th number is 8.486079 (Problem 1 - No Memo
The time for the 7 th number is 12.532179 (Problem 1 - Memo
The time for the 8 th number is 13.571108 (Problem 1 - No Memo
The time for the 8 th number is 0.321315 (Problem 1 - Memo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./problem3.py", line 7, in <module>
    t2 = timeit.Timer('fib(%s)' % i, 'from problem2 import fib').timeit()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 195, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
  File "problem2.py", line 18, in fib
    cache[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: And what conclusion did you draw from the error (now that you've updated the post)? Did you try to step through the program with pdb for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if n in cache` is the wrong logic. Your probably want `if cache[n] is not None`

`n` is supposed to represent the nth fibonacci number, so the cache is **storing** fibonacci numbers, not the indicies of them.